# maximum Manhattan Distance of ranked list

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am using the normalized manhattan distance (L1-norm) between two lists as a metric to measure how much change has happened. Let's call this `changeIdx` .This measure is basically `changeIdx=L1Norm/n` therefore, it gives an idea of the # of rank changes. For example, one change in a list of 8 items equals 0.25, and if every rank changes, then `changeIdx = 4`

To be useful, it is important to know the range. We know that the maximum manhattan distance of a ranked list can be obtained by reversing the list.

eg. ranked list of n=8

`maxl1=manhattan_distance([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])`

which is 32. I can divide this by n to get a changeIdx from 0-max distance. Which would be 0-4 in this case. (See reference)

However, say I have 8 items and I put them in a paired comparison experiment where you have to pick one of the other. This is a total of 28 comparisons (unique combinations). Here, the maximum # of picks an item can get is 7, as it sees every other item once. However, the other items do not have to be ordered. For example, a list of frequency of wins could be

`freq1=[6,5,2,2,5,7,0,1]`
`freq2=[1,2,5,6,5,2,7,0]`

The L1 distance between these is 28. The changeIdx  28/8 = 3.5

Now, if we convert this to ranks.

`rank1=[7,5.5,3.5,3.5,8,1,2]`
`rank2=[2,3.5,5.5,7,5.5,3.5,8,1]`

The l1 of these is 25. and changeIdx is 25/8= 3.125.

Clearly, these two are not equal. This is because ranking effectively 'stretches' out the frequency counts to map them to a range.

My **question** is, can these two indices be compared? Is it valid to use the frequency L1 as an index of change? Is there a better way to measure an incremental change in frequency count lists?

References

- *Pugach, Cameron, Helmut Leder, and Daniel J. Graham. "How stable are human aesthetic preferences across the lifespan?." Frontiers in human neuroscience 11 (2017): 289.*